# SQL Optimization: how to JOIN a table with itself

Tags: mysql, optimization

**I'm trying to optimize a SQL query and I am not sure if further optimization is possible.**

Here's my query:

```
SELECT someColumns
FROM (((smaller_table))) AS a
INNER JOIN (((smaller_table))) AS b
        ON  a.someColumnProperty = b.someColumnProperty
```

...the problem with this approach is that my table has half a trillion records in it.  In my query, you'll notice `(((smaller_table)))`.  I wrote that as an abbreviation for a `SELECT` statement being run on `MY_VERY_LARGE_TABLE` to reduce it's size.

`(((smaller_table)))` appears twice, and the code within is exactly the same both times.  There's no reason for me to run the same sub-query twice.  This table is several TB and I shouldn't scan through it twice just to get the same results.

**Do you have any suggestions on how I can NOT run the exact same reduction twice?**  I tried replacing the INNER JOIN line with `INNER JOIN a AS b` but got an "unrecognized table a" warning.  Is there any way to store the value of `a` so I can reuse it?

Comment: Without more information (such as what you are trying to do), your only option would be to create a temporary table.

Comment: `(((smaller_table)))` would be better described as `(((derived table)))`. IF MySQL supported common table expressions (CTE) - which may happen in the future - you could use a CTE, but as of October 2015 a temporary table as Gordon Linoff states is the only way to avoid repeating your subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts:

- Make sure there is an index on userid and dayid.
- I would ask you to define better what it is you are trying to find out.

Examples:

- What is the busiest time of the week?
- Who are the top 25 people who come to the gym the most often?
- Who are the top 25 people who utilize the gem the most?  (This is different than the one above because maybe I have a user that comes 5 times a month, but stays 5 hours per session vs a user that comes 30 times a month and stays .5 hour per session.)
- Maybe doing all days in a horizontal method (day1, day2, day3) would be better visually to try to find out what you are looking for.  You could easily put this into excel or libreoffice and color the days that are populated to get a visual "picture" of people who come consecutively.
- It might be interesting to run this for multiple months to see if what the seasonality looks like.

Comment: Any reason not to just create another table and populate it with the results from the query?  Not the most glamorous solution, but prevents the subquery from running twice.

Answer (score 0):

Alas CTE is not available in MySQL.  The ~equivalent is

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (
    INDEX(someColumnProperty)
)
SELECT ...;
```

But...

- You can't use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` because such can't be used twice in the same query.  (No, I don't know why.)
- Adding the INDEX (or PK or ...) during the CREATE (or afterwards) provides the very necessary key for doing the self join.
- You still need to worry about DROPping the table (or otherwise dealing with it).
- The choice of ENGINE for `tmp` depends on a number of factors.  If you are sure it will be "small" and has no TEXT/BLOB, then `MEMORY` may be optimal.
- In a Replication topology, there are additional considerations.